# Auto Close Simple Modal After User Moves Mouse?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am working with a web application where we need to show modal style content when a user mouses over a specific portion of the page, as they move their mouse away from that area though we want to close the modal content.

I'm currently working with [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#examples) and have it working to show, but you must click to close.  Does anyone know of a way to close based on mouse movement?  Or similar.

Or a different component that I can use.  Effectively what we are doing is showing a overly robust tooltip, that happens to be iFrame content.  So if you know of a jQuery tooltip function that would support showing an iFrame that could work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to use a tooltip plugin which actually  features the behavior you're looking after (show/hide a box when hovering an element) ?

I think the best is **[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/)**.

It can show simple tooltip, load content via ajax, display advanced content (not just text), is highly styl-able and proposes a full api to work with.

---

In the meantime, I don't know much about SimpleModal and as you don't show any javascript, I can only guess how you actually create the modal dialog.

Anyway, jQuery proposes the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method to handle the cases of entering an element with the mouse and leaving it. You use like this:

```
$('#myelement').hover(
    // this function is executed when entering the element with the mouse
    function(e) {
        // create you SimpleModal here
    },
    // this one when leaving
    function(e) {
        // close it here
        // from the SimpleModal doc, you close the currently opened modal with
        $.modal.close()
    }
);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/dKuGW/)**

Answer (score 1):

To close SimpleModal you do

```
$.modal.close()
```

So I suggest to use it together with `mouseleave()` from jQuery.

```
$("SELECTOR_FOR_YOUR_AREA").mouseleave($.modal.close);
```